# postgresql - datetime: does postgresql have datetime type like in mysql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know in mysql there is datetime type but couldn't find couterpart in postgresql. I know there is timestamp type in postgresql but that's a timestamp instead of datetime.

Thanks

Comment: It is called `timestamp` or `timestamp with timezone`.

Comment: Do you need to store values in the LOCAL time line (use `TIMESTAMP`), or WORLD time line (use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`)?

Comment: "*that's a timestamp instead of datetime*" makes no sense. Those two are literally the same thing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A MySQL `DATETIME` is equivalent to a PostgreSQL `TIMESTAMP`.

Both store a date+time value in an **undefined** time line. They assume the *time offset* or *time zone* is of no interest, or is defined by the application.